# Nuxt.js : Property or method "ip" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this message with nuxt.js : [Vue warn]: Property or method "ip" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

components/Tutorial.vue

```
<div> 

test {{ ip }}

</div>

</template>



<script>
export default {
async asyncData({ $axios }) {
  const ip = await $axios.$get('http://icanhazip.com')
  return { ip }
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: As you can see in the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/#async-data) asyncData is only for pages not for components. You probably should use the fetch hook instead

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I put the script in /pages and kept the HTML as it was, and still got the same message.
Does the fetch method block the page from loading until the result is obtained?

Comment: As far as I know fetch won't block, but what are your requirement that you need it to block?

Comment: I would like to use it as a PHP API

Comment: Okay i'm not really getting what your plan is or why you require asyncData or fetch to block the rendering. Can you get more into detail?

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo or anything else here? Do you have a Github repo?

Comment: Make sure to add `ip` to data option

Comment: This is available via `asyncData` actually @UdithIshara

Comment: What if you try returning `{ ip: ip }` ?

Comment: @bar5um Nuxt is using modern JS so no need to write it in ES5.